# How to make a POST call to the Stripe API from iOS / Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, post, stripe-payments

I'm trying to create a POST call to Stripe and having trouble figuring out 
how to make the call correctly.
Here's the API specs:

```
POST https://api.stripe.com/v1/recipients

curl https://api.stripe.com/v1/recipients \
       -u sk_test_4TyIk8adGJTfvHq9YDt4raCx: \
       -d "name=John Doe" \
       -d type=individual \
       -d tax_id=000000000 \
       -d "email=test@example.com" \
       -d "description=Recipient for John Doe"
```

Refrence for api is here: https://stripe.com/docs/api/curl#create_recipient

Here's my code so far:

```
-(void)createRecipientREST:(STPToken *)token
{
    NSString *name = @"John Doe";
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api.stripe.com/v1/recipients"]];
    NSString *params = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@:&name=%@&type=individual&card=%@",kStripeSecretKey,name,token.tokenId];
    request.HTTPMethod = @"POST";
    request.HTTPBody = [params dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request
                                   queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                       completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error)
     {
         if (error)
         {
             NSLog(@"ERROR: %@",error);
         }
         else
         {
         NSLog(@"%@", response);
         }
     }]; 
}
```

Here's the response:

```
<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x10cfcb880> { URL: https://api.stripe.com/v1/recipients } { status code: 400, headers {
 "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" = true;
 "Access-Control-Allow-Methods" = "GET, POST, HEAD, OPTIONS, DELETE";
 "Access-Control-Max-Age" = 300;
 "Cache-Control" = "no-cache, no-store";
 "Content-Length" = 187;
 "Content-Type" = "application/json;charset=utf-8";
 Date = "Fri, 15 Aug 2014 16:23:23 GMT";
 Server = nginx;
 "Strict-Transport-Security" = "max-age=31556926; includeSubDomains";
 "Stripe-Version" = "2014-08-04";
 } }
```

But I'm looking for a response like this:

```
 {
        "id": "rp_14Rb9D4UNKEkOFM8A3mxaavE",
        "object": "recipient",
        "created": 1408072379,
        "livemode": true,
        "type": "individual",
        "description": "Recipient for John Doe",
        "email": "test@example.com",
        "name": "John Doe",
        "verified": false,
        "metadata": {},
        "active_account": null,
        "cards": {
        "object": "list",
        "total_count": 0,
        "has_more": false,
        "url": "/v1/recipients/rp_14Rb9D4UNKEkOFM8A3mxaavE/cards",
        "data": []
    },
    "default_card": null
}
```

How should I modify my code to get the desired response?
Thanks ahead of time! :)

Comment: FYI, "11.2 Apps utilizing a system other than the In-App Purchase API (IAP) to purchase content, functionality, or services in an App will be rejected"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NSHTTPURLResponse` is **not** the received data, it is the response information. Use the `data` variable to the completion block.

```
completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"data: %@", data);
    NSLog(@"data: %@", [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
```

You should see the JSON.

If you really want to know what is happening sniff the network connection with Charles Proxy.